# Ionic 6 / Capacitor App not saving file - permissions added

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm testing an app with Ionic 6 / Angular / Capacitor.

I am using this capacitor api to save to file:

```
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/configuration#setting-permissions
```

Here is the code to save the file:

```
 writeSecretFile = async () => {
    await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: 'secrets/text.txt',
      data: "This is a test",
      directory: Directory.Documents,
      encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
    });
  };
```

And the trigger button:

```
<ion-button (click)="writeSecretFile()">Save test</ion-button>
```

Then I've added the button 2 lines to the xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And here is the file xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.ionic.starter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="io.ionic.starter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

After running the app and clicking the button I cannot find the file so it's not saving anything?

How can I fix this?

Comment: make sure the secrets folder is present in the Documents, you can turn "recursive" to  true in writeFile object. Also try this in try-catch. You might get a hint the catch error. XML permission statements seem fine